# Routine For Creating A Symmetric Matrix From A Given Vector In C

Tags: c, algorithm, matrix, matrix-indexing, symmetric

Lets say I have the vector

```
x = [x0, x1, x2, x3] = [0, 2, 3, 1].
```

I want to create a symmetric matrix from x. Ie a symmetric matrix that has x as the first row and first column, with x0 as the diagonal. In other words, I want a matrix X like this:

```
X = [0 2 3 1] = [x0 x1 x2 x3]
    [2 0 1 3]   [x1 x0 x3 x2]
    [3 1 0 2]   [x2 x3 x0 x1]
    [1 3 2 0]   [x3 x2 x1 x0]
```

Question:

1. How can I do this in C?
2. How can I extend this for any length vector given?

Computer science is not my area, so all of my attempts so far are quite laughable and involve loops upon loops. Am I missing something obvious?

Thank you

Comment: @EugeneSh. That is not the case for the diagonals.

Comment: Oh. Looks like I have misread the question. Though each row is just the rotation of the vector.

Comment: @EugeneSh. That is not the case for the 1st and second row.

Answer (score 2):

The trick is that the index into the **input** array is the sum of the indexes into the **output** array.
For example,

```
output[0][3] = output[1][2] = output[2][1] = output[3][0] = input[3]
```

However there are two problems with this:

First the main diagonal (top/left to bottom/right) is always the first element of the input array. That can be handled as a special case by checking if the output indexes are equal.

Then there's the problem of what to do when the sum of the **output** indexes is more than the maximum allowed **input** index. In that case, the index into the input array is calculated by a subtraction, as shown in the code below.

```
#define SIZE 4

int input[SIZE] = {0,1,2,3};
int output[SIZE][SIZE];

for (int row = 0; row < SIZE; row++)
    for (int col = 0; col < SIZE; col++)
    {
        if (row == col)                        // special case for the main diagonal
            output[row][col] = input[0];
        else if (row + col < SIZE)             // normal case for small indexes
            output[row][col] = input[row+col];
        else                                   // special case for large indexes
            output[row][col] = input[2*(SIZE-1) - (row + col)];
    }
```